# Find the expected value.

Tags: probability-theory, proof-verification

> Roll two dice and find $E[X]$ if $X$ is **(a)** the smallest number,
>   **(b)** the difference between the largest and the smallest numbers.

For the expected value I use the formula

$$E(X)=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}k\cdot p(k), \tag{1}$$

where $p(k)$ is the probability mass function (pmf) of $X$.

**(a):** Counting the possible outcomes for $X$ we get that they are $36$. We have several instances of a particular outcome, for example: the number 1 can occur in 11 of those outcomes, the number 2 can occur in 9 and so on so the probabilities of each outcome are

$P(X=1) =11/36$

$P(X=2) =9/36$

$P(X=3) =7/36$

$P(X=4) =5/36$

$P(X=5)=3/36$

$P(X=6) =1/36$

which can be written as $p(k)= P(X=k)=(2k-1)/36, \ k=1,2,...,6$. Now (1) would give me

$$E(X)=\sum_{k=1}^{6}k\cdot \frac{2k-1}{36}=\frac{161}{36}\approx 4.47.$$

I don't understand why this is incorrect-the answer is $91/36\approx2.53.$

Comment: \begin{eqnarray*}
1 \times 11+ 2 \times 9+3 \times 7+4 \times 5+5 \times 3+6 \times 1=91.
\end{eqnarray*}

Comment: You accidentally reversed your probabilities

Answer (score 1):

Your numerical probabilities are correct but you sum calculation has gone wrong because you accidentally reversed your probabilities and came out with the wrong P(X = k) equation.

You have said the P(X = k) = (2k-1)/36 but this isn't the case. P(X = k) = (2*(7-k) - 1)/36 = (13 - 2k) / 36.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Stupid mistake there. But I struggle to get the sum for (b). There are 36 outcomes there too and the probabilites are are:

$P(X=5) =2/36,$

$P(X=4) =4/36,$

$P(X=3) =6/36,$

$P(X=2) =8/36,$

$P(X=1)=10/36,$

$P(X=0)=6/36.$

It does not seem to be possible to create a sum for this from (1)?

Comment: @Parseval I don't understand, are you saying you can't create an answer to (b) that is in terms of the answer to (a)? P(X(b) = k) = (12 -2k))/36 for k=1 to 5. The P(X(b) = 0) doesn't count towards the expectation value. So, a bit forced but, E(X(b)) = SUM(1,5) ((12 - 2k) / 36) * k) = E(X(a)) - (SUM(1,5) k/36) - 6*P(X(a) = 6) = (91/36) - (15/36) - (6/36) = (70/36) = (35/18) ~ 1.94.

Comment: May I ask why $P(X=0)=6/36$ does not count towards the expected value? It's still a possible outcome.

Comment: The Expectation value is the sum of the values multiplied by their probabilities, so if the value is 0 then whatever the probability it still makes 0 contribution to the Expectation value. The effect of 0 is felt in the lower probabilities of other non-zero values.

Comment: I'm sorry, I formulated the question a bit wrong. From the formula and definition fo expected value I understand that the zero will cancel it out, but why is this intuitively true? $X=0$ is still a perfectly valid outcome?